# Java AudioSystem.GetMixerInfo truncating device name for some devices

Tags: java, windows, audio, audio-recording

I'll start this off with, this may just be a bug in openJDK:
Have tired using both:

- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 12.0.2+10)
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14+36-1461)

When I attempted to get the name of the TargetDataLine objects from the mixer info it is truncated to 32 characters, however Microsoft has added 31 characters to the string name for devices that are both Mic and Speaker devices. Meaning I have 1 character to tell devices apart, which is not helpful.

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*
...
public TargetDataLine getAudioInLineByName(String deviceName) {
    Mixer.Info[] mixerInfos = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
    for (Mixer.Info info : mixerInfos) {
        logger.debug(JsonUtils.toJson(info));
        Mixer m = AudioSystem.getMixer(info);
        Line.Info[] lineInfos = m.getTargetLineInfo();
        //Gets Mics on systems
        if (lineInfos.length >= 1 && lineInfos[0].getLineClass() == TargetDataLine.class) {
            //Pass in name if device to search for
            if (info.getName().contains(deviceName)) {
                logger.info("Match found: " + info.getName());
                return  (TargetDataLine) m.getLine(lineInfos[0]);
            }
        }
    }
    return null; 
}
```

I cleaned up the output of the debug output here:

```
   {
      "name":"Port Echo Cancelling Speakerphone (P",
      "vendor":"Unknown Vendor",
      "description":"Port Mixer",
      "version":"5.0"
   },
   {
      "name":"Port Speakers/Headphones (Realtek(R)",
      "vendor":"Unknown Vendor",
      "description":"Port Mixer",
      "version":"10.0"
   },
   {
      "name":"Echo Cancelling Speakerphone (Poly Studio)",
      "vendor":"Unknown Vendor",
      "description":"Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback",
      "version":"Unknown Version"
   },
   {
      "name":"Speakers/Headphones (Realtek(R) Audio)",
      "vendor":"Unknown Vendor",
      "description":"Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback",
      "version":"Unknown Version"
   },
   {
      "name":"Echo Cancelling Speakerphone (P",
      "vendor":"Unknown Vendor",
      "description":"Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture",
      "version":"Unknown Version"
   },
   {
      "name":"Microphone (Realtek(R) Audio)",
      "vendor":"Unknown Vendor",
      "description":"Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture",
      "version":"Unknown Version"
   }...
]
```

As you can see the name for the 'Port Mixer' and 'Capture Devices' has both been truncated to 32 characters, but the Playback has not been truncated.
Is there a workaround for this, I saw several old bugs open on java.net related to this, but they are on older versions of java and have not been touched in a couple of years.